# kubernetes pod name to be used as argument

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use the Kubernetes pod name to be used as an identifier in my container as an argument.

I have deployed my echo containers on my Kubernetes cluster using the following config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo1
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo1
        image: hashicorp/http-echo
        args:
        - "-text=echo1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5678
```

When I do "kubectl get pods":

```
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
echo1-76c689b7d-48h4v                    1/1     Running   0          19h
echo1-76c689b7d-4gq2v                    1/1     Running   0          19h
```

I want to echo the pod name by passing the pod name in my config above:

```
args:
            - "-text=echo1"
```

How do I access my pod name to be used in my args?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So a few things. First you would use the fieldRef syntax for an environment variable as shown in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/. Then you would use the env var in your argument (`"-text=$(PODNAME)"`). However this will give you the actual pod name, like `echo1-76c689b7d-48h4v`. What you want is either the deployment name or the value of the `app` label, the latter is easier to instead of `metadata.name` as the field path, use something like `metadata.labels['app']` (requires Kubernetes 1.9+).

Comment: I tried with "-text=$PODNAME".  When I curl to the service I get "$PODNAME" itself.  Do I - "text=metadata.labels['app']" ?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `$(PODNAME)` I think

Comment: (and remember you also have to configure the env var section too)